# If else inside echo in php

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

I want to change this code:

```
echo"
td class='inhoud_c' width='5%'>".$i."</td>
<td class='inhoud' width='25%'><a href='profile.php?x=".$naam."'>".$naam."</td>
<td class='inhoud_c' width='50%'>
<table border='0' cellspacing='0' style='margin: 0px;'>
    <tr>
   <td>
       <img src='".$icon."' alt='' border='0'>
  </td>
     <td>
         ".$land."
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
    <td class='inhoud_c' width='20%'>
      ".gmdate("H:i:s", $time)."
    </td>
</tr>   ";
                $i++;
```

To something like this, but I don't know how to do it:

```
<td class='inhoud_c' width='20%'>
  "if ($tijz >= 0){
      gmdate("H:i:s", $tijz);
   }
   else {
     echo "Time's Up!";
   }
</td>
```

So I want a if else statement inside echo, But when i try this the rest of my code doesn't work.

Comment: well, why not just break the huge echo into smaller parts ?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using ternary operator like this:

```
( ($tijz >= 0) ? gmdate("H:i:s", $tijz) : "Time's Up!" )
```

Then:

```
echo "
td class='inhoud_c' width='5%'>".$i."</td>
<td class='inhoud' width='25%'><a href='profile.php?x=".$naam."'>".$naam."</td>
<td class='inhoud_c' width='50%'>
<table border='0' cellspacing='0' style='margin: 0px;'>
    <tr>
   <td>
       <img src='".$icon."' alt='' border='0'>
  </td>
     <td>
         ".$land."
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
    <td class='inhoud_c' width='20%'>
      ". ( ($tijz >= 0) ? gmdate("H:i:s", $tijz) : "Time's Up!" ) ."
    </td>
</tr>   ";
                $i++;
```

Comment: How i can put a mysql query instead of "Time's Up!"?

Comment: Put the query result into a variable and then concat this var

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) for if else or something like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

```
<?php
if ($tijz >= 0) {
    echo gmdate("H:i:s", $tijz);
} else {
    echo "Time's Up!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<?php
echo $tijd > 0 ? gmdate('H:i:s', $tijd) : 'Times up!';
?>
```